# EF Core Decryption of SQL Column Level Encryption

Tags: linq, encryption, .net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

My team and I are attempting to decrypt values from a db (Azure SQL) that has column level encryption turned on; with certs stored in key vault.

Expected Result:

```
var someLinqQuery = _contex.Users.First();
someLinqQuery.SSN = "000-00-0000";
```

Actual Result:

```
var someLinqQuery = _context.Users.First();
someLinqQuery.SSN = "the var binary (encrypted) version of the ssn";
```

FWIW, this works fine w/ raw sql. But we would like the option of not doing it this way, and encrypting more data.

Also we have the azure keyvault code here:

```
 //Key Vault Code Below
    private static ClientCredential _clientCredential;

    public static void InitializeAzureKeyVaultProvider()
    {
        if (!isActivated)
        {
            _clientCredential = new ClientCredential(_applicationId, _clientKey);

            SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider azureKeyVaultProvider = new SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider(GetToken);

            Dictionary<string, SqlColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProvider> providers = new Dictionary<string, SqlColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProvider>
        {
            { SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider.ProviderName, azureKeyVaultProvider }
        };

            SqlConnection.RegisterColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProviders(providers);
            isActivated = true;

        }
    }

    public static async Task<string> GetToken(string authority, string resource, string scope)
    {
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, _clientCredential);

        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the access token");
        }
        AccessToken = result.AccessToken;
        return result.AccessToken;
    }
```

This is loaded in the startup class. I've also moved the code to other places in the app w/ the same results.

My question is this, on .net core 2.1.x and EF core 2.1.x is this possible using LINQ? Do I need to upgrade?

Comment: Could you please try to use ```BitConverter.ToString``` to decrypt.

Comment: @JimXu, all this does is convert the encrypted value to the string representation of a byte array. See example:

'var model  = new UserModel{
SSN = BitConverter.ToString(a.SSN)
};'

The 'a' value comes from a foreach loop. 
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8):

According to my research, if we want to use Always Encryption( Column Encryption), we need to use the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/11#issuecomment-494851711). Besides, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` 3.x depends on `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`, so I suggest you use EF core 3.x

For example. I do a test in the console application.

1. [Configure database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-always-encrypted-azure-key-vault?tabs=azure-powershell#create-a-table)
2. Application

   a. Install SDK

   ```
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider" Version="1.1.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.2" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.2" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" Version="5.2.7" />
   ```

   b. data model

   ```
   class Patient
   {

     public int PatientId { get; set; }
     public string SSN { get; set; }
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
     public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   c. database context

   ```
   private static Boolean isInitialized;
   public TestContext(DbContextOptions<TestContext> options) : base(options) {
            if(! isInitialized) { InitializeAzureKeyVaultProvider(); isInitialized = true; }

       }

       protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
       {
          // your sql server connnection string
           var constr = "Server=<>;Initial Catalog=<>;User ID=<>;Password=<>;Column Encryption Setting=enabled";
          SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constr);


           optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection);
       }
       public DbSet<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
           modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>().ToTable("Patients");
       }

       private static string clientId = "";
       private static string clientSecret = "";
       private static ClientCredential _clientCredential;

       private static void InitializeAzureKeyVaultProvider()
       {
            _clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

           SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider azureKeyVaultProvider =
             new SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider(GetToken);

           Dictionary<string, SqlColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProvider> providers =
             new Dictionary<string, SqlColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProvider>();

           providers.Add(SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider.ProviderName, azureKeyVaultProvider);
           SqlConnection.RegisterColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProviders(providers);
       }

       private  static async  Task<string> GetToken(string authority, string resource, string scope)
       {
           var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
           AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, _clientCredential);

           if (result == null)
               throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the access token");
           return result.AccessToken;
       }
   ```

   d. test

   ```
    static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
         DbContextOptions<TestContext> options = new DbContextOptions<TestContext>();
         var db =new TestContext(options);
         var results =db.Patients.ToListAsync().Result;
         foreach (var r in results) {
             Console.WriteLine(r.SSN);


         }

         Console.ReadLine();
     }
   ```

   [image]

Comment: Is there any way to prove that the data was encrypted?

Comment: @CaptainPrinny If you do not decrypt data,  you read data as xxxx

Comment: @JimXu  I am getting "cannot convert from 'method group' to 'TokenCredential' error